# What's the rule of getting notification of message in my inbox

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

I have some cases where I am unable to get message notification.

1. Suppose I asked a question and somebody answers it, on that answer I write a comment after some days some user gives a comment but without `@Amogh` in this case I did not get notified. Why? Author of question is I, so comment on question or any answer is supposed to get notified to me. For example visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511859/render-image-using-outputstream-in-fop). This question is posted by  me and in answer after comment  by me on 1st July User Kevin Brown,injecteer posted comment but I didn't get a notification about this.
2. In second known case, if a question is posted by some other user and I gave a comment on that after that some other users also commented on the question (without @amogh) then this that comment is not notified to me . if comment is added by author of question that also not get notified to me. Why?

It seems I only get notified when an user says `@amogh`, why?

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) on Meta.SE.

Comment: @Payeli, I apologies for the same. I'll take care of this. Sorry and Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment without explicit `@name` notifies the author of the post and the *previous commenter*, but only if the author and *one* other user are commenting. On the sample answer you linked to, Kevin Brown added a comment too, so now there is more than one user apart from the author commenting. No notifications are sent to either you or Kevin unless explicit `@name` replies are used.

From the central FAQ on the subject (see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)):

> If a user comments on their own post and there is **only one person who has previously commented**, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten.

Emphasis mine.

The same applies to a question; if you commented on a question, and another user, also not the author comments, you will not get notified because there is more than one non-author user commenting.

Comment: In sample answer Kevin Brown is wanted to give some information but just because of absence of `@Amogh` I am not et notified. Sorry but I am not convinced to this. Question is posted by me so I suppose any activity performed on question and answer is notified to me(author of question).

Comment: @Amogh: Your english is rather.. hard to follow. You can not be convinced of this all you want, but that is how it currently works.